# Does Tailwind apply directive effects the performance and is there an alternate?

Tags: css, tailwind-css

As understood every time we use **apply** directive all CSS files are searched which is leading to slow compilation. Is there way to avoid usage of apply directive and still handle complex scenarios in tailwind.